# Why Clicking One Button Affects All Buttons in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to click one button that affects(post something to our API) its specific id. However, when I clicked it, whole buttons of the page send data to our API. [Here is the little snapshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRkix.jpg). All rows has unique id as you can see, however when I clicked relative vote button in the row, it votes all rows.

My jQuery and Ajax code is here

jQuery in First.php

```
            public function getButtons() {
            $ids = $this->polls_id;
            echo $this->polls_id;

            echo "<html>";
            echo "<head>";
            echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo '$(function(){';
                    echo "$('body').on('click', 'button', function(event){";
                        echo "event.preventDefault();";
                        echo "var pollss_id = $('#" .  $ids . "').text();";
                        echo "$.ajax({";
                            echo "method: 'POST',";
                            echo "url: 'ajax.php',";
                            echo "data: {'pollss_id' : pollss_id}";
                        echo "})";
                    echo "});";
                echo "});";
                echo "</script>";
            echo "</head>";
            echo "<body>";
                echo '<div id='. $ids .'>' . $ids . '</div>';
                echo '<button type="button">Vote</button>';
            echo "</body>";
            echo "</html>";
```

Ajax.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if($_POST) {
    $polls_id = $_POST['pollss_id'];
}

function vote_poll1($user_id, $polls_id){
    $postdata = http_build_query(
                                array(
                                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                                    'poll_id' => $polls_id,
                                    'vote_value' => '1'
                                     )
                                );
    $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postdata
                                )
                 );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents('http://sitename.herokuapp.com/api/v1/polls/'. $polls_id . '/castvote', false, $context);
}

echo vote_poll1($user_id, $polls_id);
```

PS: I create object and call functions(pictures, text fields, buttons) with for loop. What might be a problem for that?

Comment: try changing this (echo "var pollss_id = $('#" .  $ids . "').text();";) to this (echo "var pollss_id = $(this).text();";)  -- this, means, this button i just clicked

Comment: I don't really understand your code. You apply the click function to every button in the document with the `$ids` so every button has the same function. I guess you should use the [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or a similar function to get the id

Comment: Because your selector is button

Comment: if you after the buttons id which should be unique then (echo "var pollss_id = $(this).attr("id");";)

Comment: @Tasos the problem is emerged from selector. I created class and assign it to my selector instead of  'button'. It solves problem. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez yeah this was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: another problem is that if you loop `getButtons` there will be multiple jquery.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez is there any solution to print buttons just underneath of the pictures? I know it occupies the server much more than I expect, however, I do not have any brilliant idea to print it for all of rows and assign specific IDs into them.

Comment: in your post i dont see img tag. how would that be loop?if its not available?maybe you can ask another question for that.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez same way with getButtons() method, I created getPollPhotos and pull datas from our API to print it image on website. I created object and I call all methods(poll photo, text field, buttons) by using loop. However, you are right. In order to solve it, detailed explanation and some other methods should be asked in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it right now you are registering a click event on every button.

So the code

```
$('#" .  $ids . "').text();
```

will run on any button click.

What you could do is add that function one time and add the pollid as a data attribute to the button itself

```
<button data-poll-id="5" type="button">Vote</button>
```

then on your function yu can get the id with jQuery's data function

```
var poll_id = $(this).data("poll-id")
```

and make your ajax call as you have it now

Comment: I delete $('body').on('click', 'button', function(event){ function and instead of it, I added $('.button').click(function(){ and I convert my button properties into <button class="button" data-poll-id=' . $ids . ' type="button">Vote</button>. After that as you said I added var pollss_id = $(this).data("poll-id") statement. And it works. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because your selector selects all buttons not specific one.

```
 echo "$('body').on('click', 'button', function(event){";
```

You should use class(.) or id(#) prefix.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. As you said I changed my function properties by calling .class.